# What I'm doing wrong with this demonstration trigonometric?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm preparing my test for this month and I'm doing a guide with a lot of exercises... But this one blow my mind.

I don't figure how to do this thing, please help.

If $x, y \in \mathbb R^+$

$$2\operatorname{arccotan} \sqrt{\frac{x}{y}} = \arccos\left(\frac{x-y}{y+x}\right)$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the expression $(x-y)/(y+x)$ reminds you of the addition formula for tangents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, using the identity $ \cos 2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta$, that
 $$\tag{1}\cos\bigl( 2\,{\rm arccot}\,{\textstyle{\sqrt x\over\sqrt y}}\,\bigr)= 1-2\,\sin^2\bigl( {\rm arccot}{\textstyle{\sqrt x\over\sqrt y}}\,\bigr).$$

To simplify 
$\sin \bigl( {\rm arccot}{\textstyle{\sqrt x\over\sqrt y}}\bigr)$, let
$\theta= {\rm arccot}{\sqrt x\over\sqrt y}$ and draw a right triangle with one non-right angle $\theta= {\rm arccot}{\sqrt x\over\sqrt y}$. Then the cotangent of $\theta$ is $\sqrt x/\sqrt y$. Thus, we may take the length  of the side of the triangle adjacent to $\theta$ to be $\sqrt x$ and the length of the  side of the triangle opposite to $\theta$ to be $\sqrt y$. The Pythagorean Theorem then gives the length of the hypotenuse of the triangle to be ${  \sqrt{x+y}}$.  Now, reading from the triangle, we have
$$\tag{2}
\sin \bigl( {\rm arccot}{\textstyle{\sqrt x\over\sqrt y}}\bigr)= {\sqrt y\over \sqrt{x+y}}
$$

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$ gives:
$$\eqalign{
\cos\bigl( 2\,{\rm arccot}\,{\textstyle{\sqrt x\over\sqrt y}}\,\bigr)= 1-2\,\sin^2\bigl( {\rm arccot}{\textstyle{\sqrt x\over\sqrt y}}\,\bigr)
&= 1-2\Bigl[{ {\sqrt y\over \sqrt{x+y}}}\Bigr]^2\cr
&={x+y\over x+y}-{2y\over x+y}\cr
&={x-y\over x+y}.
}
$$
This establishes the identity since
$$
\cos\bigl(  {\rm arccos}\,{\textstyle{x-y\over x+ y}}\,\bigr) ={x-y\over x+y}.
$$

(The cosine function is 
one-to-one on $[0,\pi]$,   ${\rm arccos}\,{\textstyle{x-y\over x+ y}}\in[0,\pi]$, and 
$2\, {\rm arccot}{\textstyle{\sqrt x\over\sqrt y}}\in(0,\pi ]$.)

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @ignaciotr I added some detail.